# GreenDAO 3 cómo modificar la clase MainGenerator

Tags: android, android-studio

Pues eso, soy nuevo en el uso de GreenDAO y me gustaría saber cómo adaptar la clase MainGenerator para crear una base de datos que almacene las rutas de imágenes que se encuentren en memoria externa.

**Clase MainGenerator**

```
package com.example;


import org.greenrobot.greendao.generator.DaoGenerator;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.generator.Entity;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.generator.Property;
import org.greenrobot.greendao.generator.Schema;



public class MainGenerator {

    private static final String PROJECT_DIR = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Schema schema = new Schema(1, "firebase.palma.com.greendao_2.db");
        schema.enableKeepSectionsByDefault();

        addTables(schema);

        try {
            /* Use forward slashes if you're on macOS or Unix, i.e. "/app/src/main/java"  */
            new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, PROJECT_DIR + "\\app\\src\\main\\java");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void addTables(final Schema schema) {
        Entity user = addUser(schema);
        Entity repo = addRepo(schema);

        Property userId = repo.addLongProperty("userId").notNull().getProperty();
        user.addToMany(repo, userId, "userRepos");
    }

    private static Entity addUser(final Schema schema) {
        Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");
        user.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
        user.addStringProperty("name").notNull();
        user.addShortProperty("age");

        return user;
    }

    private static Entity addRepo(final Schema schema) {
        Entity repo = schema.addEntity("Repo");
        repo.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
        repo.addStringProperty("title").notNull();
        repo.addStringProperty("language");
        repo.addIntProperty("watchers_count");

        return repo;
    }
}
```

Comment: La he obtenido de un tutorial que estoy siguiendo pero no me he atrevido a modificar nada por el momento, a excepción de la ruta donde se crearán las clases al hacer el Run()